# помогите с навигацией по DOM

Tags: javascript

какие способы есть, чтобы "добраться" к родителям родителей элементов, на чистом js?

если в jquery можно `.parent().parent();` писать, то как, допустим, тыкая на пятый div, можно добраться до первого?

```
<div class="1"> 
     <div class="2"> 
      <div class="3"> 
        <div class="4"> 
          <div class="5">
            <div class="6"> ....
```

Comment: охренеть ну и вопросы пошли, а parentChild в гугле нет?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp

Comment: 24 секунды у меня ушло чтоб найти ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: кому охренеть , кому - нет, спасибо за изобилие данных

Comment: Вот, специально для вас - http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ подарок за адекватность

Comment: @Darth, а что за `parentChild`?

Comment: Смешались в кучу кони,люди) Давно с dom не делал ничего серьезного, перепутал.

Answer (score 2):

Родитель доступен через parentNode. Если долго идти от одного элемента к другому, то рано или поздно дойдёшь до корня DOM, то есть до document.documentElement, а затем и document.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно написал [@pepel_xD](/users/194692/pepel-xd), родительский элемент получается через свойство `.parentNode`. Вот так можно в цикле добраться от любого элемента `el` наверх:

```
for(;el  &&  el != document; el = el.parentNode) { ... }
```

Покликайте на вложенных дивах в этом демо:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("out");
function _click(e){
  var el = e.target, html = '';
  e.stopPropagation();
  for(; el && el != document; el = el.parentNode)  html += el.className + ' '
  out.innerHTML = html;
}

Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(".c1,.c2,.c3,.c4,.c5,.c6")
).map(function(el){ el.addEventListener('click',_click, true);});
```

```css
div {min-height:10px;min-width:10px;border:1px solid #999;padding:20px;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="c1"> 
 <div class="c2"> 
  <div class="c3"> 
   <div class="c4"> 
    <div class="c5">
     <div class="c6" id="out">понажимайте
</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Иногда можно идти наоборот: извне внутрь. Часто бывает нужно ловить события вложенных элементов, которых много. И для этого достаточно слушать их общего родителя:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("out");
document.getElementById('root').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  out.innerHTML = "Вы нажали на див " + e.target.className;
});
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 10px;
  min-width:10px;
  border:1px solid #999;
  padding:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="1" id="root"> 
 <div class="2"> 
  <div class="3"> 
   <div class="4"> 
    <div class="5">
     <div class="6" id="out">понажимайте внутри
</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```